# List<int> assignable from IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, types

In the below example, I want to throw an exception if `something` is of type `IEnumerable`:

```
var something = new List<int>();

if (something.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEnumerable)))
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Cannot create a key from type IEnumerable");
}
```

From what I understand, `IsAssignableFrom` should return true in the above case since `List<int>` certainly is an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: You can check with GetInterfaces()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current code checks if you can assign `IEnumerable` to `List<int>`, that's why it returns false.

You need to do it the other way around:

```
typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(something.GetType())
```

Quick test:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(List<int>)));
Console.WriteLine(typeof(List<int>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEnumerable)));
```

Prints

```
True
False
```

Comment: What's wrong with `is`? E.g. `if (something is IEnumerable)`

Answer (score 1):

You can using one the following way:

```
if(something.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(IEnumerable)))
    throw;
```

Or

```
if(something.GetType().IsAssignableTo<IEnumerable>())
    throw;
```

Or

```
if(typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(something.GetType())
   throw;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var something = new List<int>();    
 if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(something.GetType()))
 {
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Cannot create a key from type IEnumerable");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `is` operator?

```
var something = new List<int>();

if (something is IEnumerable)
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Cannot create a key from type IEnumerable");
}
```